# Fuzzy logic control model

Tags: r, fuzzy

I'm new in fuzzy logic modeling. I'm using the package "sets" in R. Starting form a database of crisps variables of 8 input varialbes and 1 output variable, I performed the fuzzyfication and I assigned a membership function to each variables (inputs and output). I'm now stucking with the definition of the fuzzy rules.

I would like to ask if we have the same consequent from different rules, how are these rules processed? I read that it's possible for this problem to assign a weight to each rule? Is it the correct way to proceed? There's some one how has already experiences with this issue?